# session storage is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried for session storage functionality in javascript. I stored a dynamic data in old.html file & tried to retrieve it in new.html webpage. The getItem returns "null" in new.html page.

My old.html file has;

```
<script>
var name=document.createTextNode("All the Best");
sessionStorage.setItem("data",name);</script>
```

And new.html file has;

```
<script>
var newdata=sessionStorage.getItem('data');
alert(newdata); </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session storage stores strings, not DOM nodes. Store the string directly:

```
<script>
sessionStorage.setItem("data", "All the Best");
</script>

<script>
var newdata=sessionStorage.getItem('data');
alert(newdata);
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any method to store DOM nodes in sessionStorage?

Comment: I am trying to pass data in DOM nodes from one html file to another html file.

Comment: No. You will have to store something else and create the DOM nodes when you read the data. You could store the HTML, but I would recommend considering a different approach. IMO you should store data, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As Dark Falcon said, web (or session) storage can only store String values.
You could try to store the string representation of the dom element(maybe with innerHTML) you want to save.

```
var data = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
sessionStorage.setItem("data", data);
```

and later on retrive it in the other file:

```
var newdata=sessionStorage.getItem('data');
document.getElementById("anotherfileID").innerHTML = newdata;
```

Although, I dont think passing one DOM element from one HTML file to another is the best thing to do. what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I will receive set of dynamic data from webservice & load it in a html page. Then i will select few data's  & move those few data's into another html page.

Comment: Ok, then wouldnt it be better to use JSON instead ? Does this apply to your case or you really need to move only a few of this data ?

Comment: no.I'm restricted to use Javascript only. When i select a option a 1st html page & click a button, that selected option must move to next html page.